# how to pass a argument to choose sql statement in spring API?

Tags: java, sql-server, spring

Now that I write two API, both of their process are similar,but difference in sql statement.

My problems are:

Can I merge into one process by a argument, which role of argument is used to select the SQL statemnt?

How to design this SQL statement?

How to build this process?

```
@RequestMapping(value="/positions" ,method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaTypes.JSON_UTF_8)
public List<WeeklyOpenPosition> getWeeklyOpenPositions(@RequestParam(value="startDate",defaultValue="20160601") String startDate
        ,@RequestParam(value="endDate", defaultValue="20160701") String endDate){

        return weeklyReportServiceImpl.getWeeklyOpenPositions(startDate,endDate);

}

@RequestMapping(value="/currentlypos" ,method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaTypes.JSON_UTF_8)
public List<WeeklyOpenPosition> getWeeklyCurrentlyOpenPositions(@RequestParam(value="startDate",defaultValue="20160601") String startDate
        ,@RequestParam(value="endDate", defaultValue="20161201") String endDate){

        return weeklyReportServiceImpl.getWeeklyCurrentlyOpenPositon(startDate, endDate);

}
```

1.`getWeeklyOpenPositions()` invoke:

```
SELECT * FROM Report WHERE Open_TS BETWEEN '20160101' AND '20161230'
```

2.`getWeeklyCurrentlyOpenPositions()` invoke:

```
SELECT * FROM Report WHERE Open_TS BETWEEN '20160101' AND '20161230' AND close_TS>NOW()
```

Comment: This is a SQL question rather than a Java-related one, right? Do you have to use a static query or can you construct it at run-time? Also, why do you want to merge the queries together?

Comment: Yep, this question focus on query design . the purpose of merge the queries is to support one processed API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is the key point.

```
params = "myParam=myValue"
```

this link may be helpful to understand.
[enter link description here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)

```
@GetMapping(path = "/pets/{petId}", params = "myParam=myValue")
public void findPet(@PathVariable String ownerId, @PathVariable String  petId, Model model) {
// implementation omitted
}
```

Following code can integrate two paths to one method

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/employee/remove","/employee/delete"})
```

[reference](http://stacktips.com/tutorials/java/spring/how-spring-controller-request-mapping-works-in-spring-mvc)

in your case

```
 @RequestMapping(value={"/currentlypos","/positions"},params = "myParam=myValue" ,method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaTypes.JSON_UTF_8)
```

if you are asking SQL level processing

```
getWeeklyOpenPositions(boolean flagCurrently){
String query="SELECT * FROM Report WHERE Open_TS BETWEEN '20160101' AND '20161230'";

if(flagCurrently)
{
 query=query+ " AND close_TS>NOW()";
} 
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sanka, your sharing link help me understand Spring MVC better,and resolve my problem.

Comment: my pleasure Victor